# How to extract excel cell values delimited with filters?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

In the each cell in a column I have this information in the cells:

A1 values:

`Depth=standard;Size=1 section;Doors=hinged solid;Interior configuration=shelves;Compressor HP=1/2 HP;Interior finish=stainless steel;Exterior finish=stainless steel;Refrigeration=top mount self-contained`

A2 values:

`Top openings=  6 pan;Size=1 section;Compressor HP=1/6 HP;Style=drawers;Exterior finish=stainless steel;Interior finish=stainless steel;Refrigeration=rear mounted`

A3,A4,A5 etc all follow similar formats

I need some method of abstracting out the following information into its own cells:

[image]

I need each semicolon separated value to be checked if there is a column name for it already, if not, make a new column and put all corresponding values where they need to be

I thought about using text->columns and then using index/match but I haven't been able to get my match criteria to work correctly. Was going to do this for each unique column. Or do I need to use VBA?

Comment: My guess is you need VBA.

Comment: You probably could do this with formulae, but I would do it with VBA. You could use Split to break up the strings by ';' and then Split each of them by '=', look for a heading match and place the second element in the appropriate column. You need to have a stab yourself first and then come back if and when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution below works as intended but the data wasn't as formatted as I originally thought.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Auto_Open()

MsgBox ("Welcome to the delimiter file set.")


End Sub

'What this program does:
'http://i.imgur.com/7MVuZLt.png

Sub DelimitFilter()

Dim curSpec As String
Dim curSpecArray() As String
Dim i As Integer, IntColCounter As Integer, iCounter As Integer, argCounter As Integer
Dim WrdString0 As String, WrdString1 As String
Dim dblColNo As Double, dblRowNo As Double

Worksheets(1).Activate

'Reference to cell values that always have data associated to them
Range("W2").Activate

'checks for number of arguments to iterate through later
Do

    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    argCounter = argCounter + 1

Loop

'Check # of arguments
Debug.Print (argCounter)

'Values to delimit
Range("X2").Activate
IntColCounter = 1

'Loop each row argument
For iCounter = 0 To argCounter

    'Set var to activecell name
    dblColNo = ActiveCell.Column
    dblRowNo = ActiveCell.Row

    'Grab input at active cell
    curSpecArray() = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ";")

    'Ignore empty rows
    If Not IsEmpty(curSpecArray) Then

        'Iterate every delimited active cell value at that row
        For i = LBound(curSpecArray) To UBound(curSpecArray)

            'Checks for unique attribute name, if none exists, make one
            WrdString0 = Split(curSpecArray(i), "=")(0)

            'a large range X1:ZZ1 is used as there are many unique column names
            If IsError(Application.Match(WrdString0, Range("X1:ZZ1"), 0)) Then  'if NOT checks if value exists
                Cells(1, dblColNo + IntColCounter).Value = WrdString0
                IntColCounter = IntColCounter + 1
            End If

            'Output attribute value to matching row and column
            WrdString1 = Trim(Split(curSpecArray(i), "=")(1))
            Debug.Print (WrdString1)
            Cells(dblRowNo, -1 + dblColNo + Application.Match(WrdString0, Range("X1:ZZ1"), 0)).Value = WrdString1


        Next i

    End If

    'Iterate Next row value
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

Next iCounter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go with something like this, though you'll have to update the sheet name and probably where you want the final data located.

```
Sub SplitCell()
    Dim DataFromCell, FoundCell
    Dim Testing, Counted, LastCol
    For Each c In Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
        Testing = Split(c.Value, ";")
        Range("B" & c.row + 1).Value = "A" & c.row
        Counted = UBound(Testing)
        For Each x In Testing
            DataFromCell = Split(x, "=")
            With Sheet2
                Set FoundCell = .Cells.Find(What:=DataFromCell(0), after:=.Cells(1, 2), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=1, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
            End With
            If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                Cells(c.row + 1, FoundCell.Column).Value = DataFromCell(1)
            End If
            If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                LastCol = Sheet2.Cells(1, Sheet2.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                Cells(1, LastCol + 1).Value = DataFromCell(0)
                Cells(c.row + 1, LastCol + 1).Value = DataFromCell(1)
            End If
        Next x
    Next c
End Sub
```

**Edit**

Since the above was giving you errors you could try this one:

```
Sub SplitCell()
    Dim DataFromCell, FoundCell
    Dim Testing, Counted, LastCol
    For Each c In Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
        Testing = Split(c.Value, ";")
        Range("B" & c.row + 1).Value = "A" & c.row
        Counted = UBound(Testing)
        For Each x In Testing
            DataFromCell = Split(x, "=")
            LastCol = Sheet2.Cells(1, Sheet2.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            With Sheet2
                FoundCell = Application.Match(DataFromCell(0), Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, LastCol)), 0)
                'Set FoundCell = .Cells.Find(What:=DataFromCell(0), after:=.Cells(1, 2), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=1, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
            End With
            If Not IsError(FoundCell) Then
                Cells(c.row + 1, FoundCell + 1).Value = DataFromCell(1)
            End If
            If IsError(FoundCell) Then

                Cells(1, LastCol + 1).Value = DataFromCell(0)
                Cells(c.row + 1, LastCol + 1).Value = DataFromCell(1)
            End If
        Next x
    Next c
End Sub
```

Only changed a few things so that it is using `Match` instead of `Find`

Comment: I just finished writing my code right as you posted this. Took me awhile though, had to spent alot of time going through VBA tutorials for the past 1-2 weeks. Here it is: https://github.com/AnacondaPython/CodeSnippets/blob/master/excelVBA/DelimitFilter.vbs

Comment: also I tried running your code (using A1, A2, A3, A4, etc) as the cell value input reference. But I got this error. http://i.imgur.com/BhUOOEk.png

Comment: I'm entirely sure about the error, but here's what MSDN says about it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264133.aspx

Comment: sorry the error I got was 424 after I turned off breakmode  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251554.aspx

Comment: Is there a value in the variable DataFromCell(0)? That might cause this error if it is trying to look for `nothing`.

Comment: You could also change this line to use `MATCH` something like: `set FoundCell = Application.MATCH(DataFromCell(0),Range(Cells(1,2),Cells(1,LastCol)),0)`   You would also have to move the `LastCol = ` up higher so that you can use is sooner.